# LFTP Put file in specific directory?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm working on the following bash script that I need to upload specific files that are over 10 MB:

```
#!/bin/sh

FTP_HOST=ftp.ftphost.com
FTP_USER=myftpuser
FTP_PASS=securepassword

[[ -n "$1" ]] || { echo "Usage: findlarge [PATHNAME]"; exit 0 ; }
FILES=`find "$1" -type f -size +10000k -printf '%p;'`

OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=";"
FILES_ARRAY=( $FILES )
IFS="$OLD_IFS"

for fl in "${FILES_ARRAY[@]}"
 do
   INVERSE=`${fl//\/var\/www\/html/\/public_html}`
   lftp -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASS -e "cd '${INVERSE}'; put '${fl}';quit" $FTP_HOST
 done
```

It's used for a specific CDN that needs larger files uploaded to their servers what it's attempting to do and where I don't know how to continue is the files on the host side are found at `/var/www/html/` but the remote server needs them placed at `/public_html/`. I need the same file structure on the remote server as I do on the host server.

The issue that I'm running into is `$INVERSE` still includes the actual file name and the path.. I need a way to trim off the filename from the INVERSE variable so I can properly place files in the correct directory.

Does anybody know of a regex statement that can take something like:

```
/public_html/path/to/file/filename.zip
```

and change it to

```
/public_html/path/to/file/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(dirname "$INVERSE")
```

Does exactly what you want =)

Also, using regex with sed:

```
$(echo "$INVERSE" | sed -e 's,/[^/]*$,/,')
```

Explaining the regex:

1. Match a slash
2. Match as many characters that aren't slashes as you can
3. Match the end of the line

On the replacement, we just make sure to not remove the last slash.

Answer (score 1):

With bash *parameter expansion* :

```
$ x=/public_html/path/to/file/filename.zip
$ echo ${x%/*}/
/public_html/path/to/file/
```

It have advantage of using a bash *built in*, so it's very light.

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe